# manage sdf data in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce

Last year, I used VS2010 to develop a Winforms application. Now, I changed to VS2013 and I faced some problems.

I couldn't find a way to manage SQL Server Compact Edition database files (`.sdf`) in VS2013. Although I have installed an add-in from this [website](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1)

But I can only see the top 200 rows of data in the `.sdf`, I can't open connection in order to add more data with code.

Is there any solution for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options in the addin, and you change 200 to any number

Could you clarify what you mean by: "cant open connection in order to add more data with code" ?